# Migrate from Fabric Crashlytics to Firebase Crashlytics

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, crashlytics, google-fabric

I am trying to migrate from Fabric to Firebase Crashlytics but it is not going through. I am already logged in and the system still asks me to login. Moreover the sign in with Google to get started button does not respond. When I click on the small button beside profile, it redirects me to the Fabric dashboard but I still see no option whatsoever to connect both the accounts. Can you Please help me here?

[image]

Comment: I get the same exact issue.

Comment: @ems305 were to able to resolve it ?

Comment: I tried in safari and it worked.!!

Comment: Worked for me on Chrome today

Comment: Still doesn't work with Chrome and Firefox. Works only in safari =(

Answer (score 1):

It seems that using safari has helped but also, using incognito mode should work.

Answer (score -1):

Incognito mode should work. It force user to enter the credentials (i.e user name and passwords) and if issue still persist check, if you have an aggressive adds blocker plugins or inspect the developer mode for any 400 and reach our "support@fabric.io"